# replace function in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i want to substitute words in a given list but its so hard when the replacing word is given by list

for example (myreplace '((dog cat)(cute lovely)) '(my dog is cute)) -> (my cat is lovely)

help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive version for you:

```
(defun myreplace (subst-alist replace-in)
  (when replace-in
    (let ((found (assoc (car replace-in) subst-alist :test #'eq)))
      (cons 
       (if found
           (cadr found)
         (car replace-in))
       (myreplace subst-alist (cdr replace-in))))))
```

And here's an iterative version, if you prefer that approach:

```
(defun myreplace (subst-alist replace-in)
  (let (result)
    (dolist (word replace-in (reverse result))
      (let ((found (assoc word subst-alist :test #'eq)))
        (push (if found (cadr found) word)
              result)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `reduce` to call `substitute` for each of the old-new pairs, incrementally transforming the original sequence:

```
(defun myreplace (substitutions sequence)
  (reduce (lambda (seq substitution)
            (destructuring-bind (old new) substitution
              (substitute new old seq)))
          substitutions
          :initial-value sequence))
```

EDIT: Trey's idea to use `assoc` (not `assq`, that's Emacs Lisp) for finding a substitution is very nice. Using that can be simplified by using an operator that has built-in support for building a new list, i.e. `mapcar` or `loop` with the `collect` clause:

```
(defun myreplace (substitutions list)
  (mapcar (lambda (elt)
            (let ((substitution (assoc elt substitutions)))
              (if substitution
                  (second substitution)
                  elt)))
          list))
```

or

```
(defun myreplace (substitutions list)
  (loop for elt in list
     for substitution = (assoc elt substitutions)
     when substitution collect (second substitution)
     else collect elt))
```

Comment: Thanks, I slipped into Emacs lisp, not common lisp.